# Android Studio uses too much CPU

Tags: android-studio, cpu-usage

I'm running AS 1.2.2. on OSX 10.10.3 The CPU usage swings wildly up and down. Trying to edit anything is a real pain - deleting characters, typing, type-checking - all are slow because Studio is consuming a huge amount of resources.  I can press a key and must wait sometimes 5 seconds before it updates on the screen

Anyone else has this problem and figure out how to make Android Studio usable again.

Comment: I have this problem but cannot find an answer.  It seems like more people should be reporting this problem.

Comment: Seriously? No one else has this issue?   Goddamn studio is driving me nuts

Comment: Now AS V2.2.2 consumes even more CPU and disk resource every time I run a test.

Comment: Well, this is crazy. As soon as I start typing my CPU usage goes nuts. Even with Highlight level at "Syntax". I have disables VCS integrations and such, but still. I am on MacBook Pro 2012 Core i7 (2.1 GHz), 8 GB RAM, 256 SSD.